# Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: xcode, string, swift, nsdata

I'm writing codes on swift in XCode. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        let notificationSettings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        print("TOKEN:", deviceToken);

        let token = String(data: deviceToken, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        let myUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://......php?id=" + token);

        print("URL:",fileURLWithPath: "http://......php?id=" + token);

    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

  /*  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    }*/


    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Compiler gives me an error on the `func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {`" and it says me "`Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to expected argument type` `'String'`"... but I can't understand the way to solve the problem. So, can somebody help me to correct the error?

Comment: What is the result when you print the token

Comment: this is the result "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) " another error

Comment: @MatteoRK22 You need to unwrap optional value - take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe this, for sending token to the server. Worked well for me

```
    var token: String = "\(deviceToken)"
    let rawtoken = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "")
    let cleantoken = rawtoken.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "")
    var finaltoken = cleantoken.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

Final token is the one that you are supposed to use.

Source was Udemy online courses.

Answer (score 2):

```
var charSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")
var tokenStr: String = (deviceToken.description as NSString)
            .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(characterSet)
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "") as String

print(deviceTokenString)
```

Try that

Comment: your answer was 9 seconds before mine haha

Answer (score -1):

Note that the token is BINARY, so you cannot easily convert it to a string (no UTF8!).
It is a good practice to convert it to hex:

```
let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
var tokenString = ""

for var i = 0; i < deviceToken.length; i++ {
    tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
}

print("Push token: \(tokenString)")
```